# NetBeans 8.0.2 not recognizing python plataform. How to solve this issue?

Tags: python, netbeans-8

I have installed in my pc the free version of [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) that works good as python interpreter.

But I was trying to move to a free IDE and I choose to make my Netbeans 8.0.2 to be able to run Python. After some research I found this [post](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81) that shows how to accomplish this task.
Infortunately when I try to open a new Python project I have one error "Valid plataform has to be selected" , "wrong python plataform", as you can see picture below:
[image]

After some research I found same problem for old version of NetBeans. It was not supposed to have this issue to 8.0.2 version. [Link](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=149120)

It seems that there is no python installed in the system. I have no found Environment variables, PATH to Python at ControlPainel>System>AdvencedSystemsSettings>SystemProperties>EnviromentVariable .Or it seems that Canopy Python can not be recognize by NetBeans.

When I try to run Python from command it loads Canopy libraries before to show python propmt ">>>" as you can see below:
[image]

I dont know how to solve this issue. I was think about to uninstall Cancopy and try to install python by hand. Is there another idea? One last question, where should be located the Python executable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and fixed the issue by downloading Python separately and manually adding it to the list of available platforms. It's very easy to do, and only takes a few minutes. After you're done following the instructions for installing the Python plugin (https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81), download a supported version of Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ (I went with version 3.4.2). Next, open the "New Project" window in Netbeans and choose a Python project. After clicking "Next", click the "Manage...." button located next to the "Python Platform" dropdown menu. A new window titled "Python Platform Manager" will pop up and all of the fields will be empty because a Python platform hasn't been added yet. The goal here is to add the version of Python you just downloaded, so to do that, click the "New" button located on the left hand panel and locate the file "python.exe". It should be inside of the folder that was created when you downloaded Python. When you find this file, click "Open" to add it to "Console Command". All of the other fields will be immediately populated with the necessary info and automatically save this platform as an option. Click "Close" to return to the "New Python Project" window and the version of Python you downloaded should now be listed as an available platform. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I had to install python by hand, as You did. It worked very well. Thanks

Comment: It completely did not work for me. I had to do a minor modification in the end

Comment: In case you are having trouble locating the "python.exe", then go to C:\ and type "python.exe" to search.

Answer (score 9):

The installation instruction given by turnipHead did not work completely for me for netbeans 8.0.2 and python 2.7 in windows 7 environment.  There was a slight modification in the end while choosing python platform

Steps

1. Install python plugins as  https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81
2. Install python manually from https://www.python.org/downloads/
3. open the "New Project" window in Netbeans
4. Choose a Python project
5. After clicking "Next", click the "Manage...." button located next to the
   "Python Platform" drop down menu
6. Click New button  from the left box and then point it to the installed python.exe
7. All other columns will automatically fill up
8. Click close

You should see the selected python version in the python platform

PS: On the similar note please see http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html#netbeans for jython installation in netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Install python plugins from https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81
- Install python manually from https://www.python.org/downloads/
- Open the "New Project" window in Netbeans
- Choose a Python project
- After clicking "Next", click the "Manage...." button located next to the
  "Python Platform" drop down menu
- Click New button from the left box and then point it to the installed python.exe
- All other columns will automatically fill up
- Click close

Python 3.4.2 - 2014-10-13 should be loaded, then there will be no problem.