# Problems with Python Platform Manager on NetBeans: When running a Python program it opens Python Setup instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netbeans

So, I just installed Python 3.6.0 on NetBeans 8.2 using the method described in this answer:

[NetBeans 8.0.2 not recognizing python plataform. How to solve this issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037159/netbeans-8-0-2-not-recognizing-python-plataform-how-to-solve-this-issue)

> I ran into the same problem and fixed the issue by downloading Python
>   separately and manually adding it to the list of available platforms.
>   It's very easy to do, and only takes a few minutes. After you're done
>   following the instructions for installing the Python plugin
>   (https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81),
>   download a supported version of Python from
>   https://www.python.org/downloads/ (I went with version 3.4.2). Next,
>   open the "New Project" window in Netbeans and choose a Python project.
>   After clicking "Next", click the "Manage...." button located next to
>   the "Python Platform" dropdown menu. A new window titled "Python
>   Platform Manager" will pop up and all of the fields will be empty
>   because a Python platform hasn't been added yet. The goal here is to
>   add the version of Python you just downloaded, so to do that, click
>   the "New" button located on the left hand panel and locate the file
>   "python.exe". It should be inside of the folder that was created when
>   you downloaded Python. When you find this file, click "Open" to add it
>   to "Console Command". All of the other fields will be immediately
>   populated with the necessary info and automatically save this platform
>   as an option. Click "Close" to return to the "New Python Project"
>   window and the version of Python you downloaded should now be listed
>   as an available platform. Hope this helps!

But every time I try to run a program it just opens a Python Modify setup, instead of running the actual program:

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this?

UPDATE: Do you think it's related to the Python release version I'm using?

The guy in the answer used: 3.4.2 (October 2014) on NetBeans 8.0.2 (November 2014).

I'm using: 3.6.0 (December 2016) on NetBeans 8.2 (October 2016).

Comment: I am using python on NB 8.2 and it works fine. I won't it is as good as it is with java. But it is functional.

Comment: The installation is pretty straight-forward. Let me know in case you face any issues. :)

Comment: @frederick99 Did you also install it using this method? If so, which Python version are you currently using? All you have to do is open NB, go to New Project, select Python, and in the Name and Location window click on Manage and and that tells you the version you're using.

Comment: I have python 3.6 installed on my computer. However, in NB, it says Jython 2.7.

Comment: @ frederick99 I fixed it already, apparently I was selecting the python.exe installer instead of the python.exe interpreter, haha.